# Прописная или строчная буква: как пишется словосочетание "всадники Апокалипсиса"?

Tags: орфография, семантика, прописная-строчная, словосочетания

Понятно, что Мор, Война, Голод и Смерть в данном случае пишутся с прописной, поскольку это имена (в/В)садников (отличаются в зависимости от перевода). Но как пишется само это словосочетание: "(в/В)садники (а/А)покалипсиса", или просто "(в/В)садники", в том же значении?

Теоретически всадники — они и в Африке всадники, то же, что наездники, поэтому разве есть ли смысл писать с прописной? Ну а в сокращённом варианте, без слова "апокалипсис"? Что касается этого слова, зачем писать его с прописной, ведь это в значении "конец света", а не книги (см. [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=215933)), разве не так?

В "Нацкорпусе" почему-то находятся варианты, где "апокалипсис" с прописной (см., к примеру, [здесь](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%20%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0) и [здесь](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0)). Почему? Как правильно-то? Чем это объясняется?

**ДОПОЛНЕНО**

"Грамота.ру" в итоге ответила, что правильно: "всадники Апокалипсиса" (см. [Грамоту.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309597)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что правильно так: ***в**садники **А**покалипсиса.*

[В словарях](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81):
***А**пока́липсис*, -а (часть Нового Завета) и ***а**пока́липсис*, -а (конец света).
АПОКАЛИПСИС, -а; м. [от греч. *apokálypsis* — откровение].
**1.** [***с прописной буквы***] В христианстве: одна из книг Нового Завета, содержащая мистические пророчества о "конце света".
**2.** Конец света, гибель всего живого на Земле. // О событии, грозящем большими жертвами и разрушениями на всей Земле.

В качестве примера можно вспомнить русских богатырей: Илью Муромца, Добрыню Никитича  и Алёшу Поповича. Каждый из них имеет имя, которое пишется с прописной буквы, но само слово "богатырь" (как и "всадник"), конечно же, пишется со строчной.

[Васнецов В.М. «Богатыри» («Три **б**огатыря»)](https://www.msk-guide.ru/page_21398.htm)

Comment: А что, если в названии "Три богатыря" "три" — это глагол в повелительном наклонении?..

Comment: Хоть три богатыря, хоть растирай, все равно — ***б**огатыря*.

Comment: Богатыри и всадники — это  далеко не одно и то же. У нас обычные богатыри, а там символические всадники. Аналогия неудачная.

Comment: Ну зачем же ж так категорично — "неудачная"? Можно ведь и *круглостоловых* (или *круглостольных*?) рыцарей припомнить.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что ничего припоминать не надо – каждая задача имеет СВОЕ решение: что верно там, неверно здесь. Неужели это не кажется очевидным?

Answer (score 2):

*Апокалипсис* пишется с прописной буквы, поскольку это 1) название книги в составе Библии; 2) уникальное событие, в отличие от тех чрезвычайных ситуаций, которые называются "апокалипсисами" в переносном смысле.
В словосочетании *всадники Апокалипсиса* "всадники" пишутся со строчной буквы.

Answer (score 2):

**Как правильно?**

Самое интересное то, что все слова могут писаться как **с прописной, так и со строчной буквы** — и всё это будет правильно.

**Апокалипсис** обычно используется как имя собственное (название книги, уникальное событие.

**Всадники,** как правило, пишутся со строчной буквы, но вот название известной гравюры Дюрера: "Четыре Всадника Апокалипсиса". Четыре — первое слово в названии, а Всадники у художника имеют особый трагический смысл — в этом случае особо важные слова могут писаться прописной буквы.

А это **современная трактовка** (все слова со строчной буквы): апокалипсис в переносном (нарицательном) значении, да и всадники  тоже другие: вирус, война, голод и новый мировой порядок.

P.S.  Надо все-таки **расширять сознание**, определяя правильное и неправильное. Но это мое личное мнение :)) А Грамота.ру отвечает по конкретному содержанию книги. Но не факт, что в Нацкорпусе речь тоже всегда идет о Новом завете.

И вот уже возникает **непонимание**: "Почему? Как правильно-то? Чем это объясняется?"

Comment: Расширю сознание, определю правильное и неправильное. В подавляющем большинстве случаев в названии дюрерской гравюры "всадники" пишутся со строчной буквы. *Необычайной силой экспрессии из этой серии отличается гравюра «Четыре **в**садника Апокалипсиса» (Государственная галерея, Карлсруэ).*

Comment: https://books.google.ee/books?id=SF4TBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5+%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0+%D0%B4%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80&source=bl&ots=6pzBW4Vx7E&sig=ACfU3U2SAfsIfEanLtFGZdYsgUTai08yqA&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ28aS19X3AhXLlIsKHR7vBxk4bhDoAXoECBQQAw#v=onepage&q=%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B5%20%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80&f=false

Comment: Вот это правильно, расширяйте и дальше. Гугл печатает все что попадется, вы же обратите внимание на авторитетные источники. Но главное-то не в этом. Если вам встретится запись с прописной буквы, то не надо говорить, что это неправильно – автор имеет полное право выбрать такой вариант. Другими словами, если даже не написал, то мог бы написать. Тема-то ведь не совсем обычная, это же не сказка «Три медведя», не стоит все одним аршином мерить.

Comment: Если бы не было обозначено количество, то я бы всё сочетание написала бы с прописной буквы – Всадники Апокалипсиса.  Не простые это всадники, а условные, символические.